# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) when uploading an image

Tags: laravel

Im trying to upload a picture from my registration form but I get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error).

It only happens in the User default model given by laravel. Does this really persist when using this model?

Comment: Check your ```storage/logs/laravel.log``` and see what the actual error was.

Comment: Ok i'll check for it. Kindly guide me throught his

Comment: I don't understand all of this

Comment: Go to the very last lot of related messages and paste it here

Comment: #79 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\mypharma\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\xampp-2\\htdo...')

Comment: #77 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\mypharma\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#78 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\mypharma\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#79 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\mypharma\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\xampp-2\\htdo...')
#80 {main}

Comment: i reinstalled xampp twice wew :')

Comment: There should be a human readable message. Above what you copy and pasted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134289/discussion-between-a-sand-and-ashmenhennett).